# In R plot arima fitted model with the original series

Tags: r, time-series

I was using GRETL. There, when I do the forecasting for the validation of the arima model, I will get the fitted series in blue line and the original series in red line. Later, I switched to R and here I could not find any command to do the same. I am using Arima model from forecast package.

details,

In GRETL I use to do model->time series -> arima -> forecast. It will automatically print the fitted and the original series. Any idea to do the same on R?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This question is fairly open ended, but here is a very, very basic answer. Starting directly from one of the examples provided in the help files for `Arima` in the `forecast` package:

```
fit <- Arima(WWWusage,order=c(3,1,0))
```

You say you want the original series in red and the fitted series in blue:

```
plot(fit$x,col="red")
lines(fitted(fit),col="blue")
```

which produces a plot that looks something like this:

[image: arima]

Comment: The last comment is a little unfair - it's not really that basic a question. Your answer is hardly info you'll find in the intro, and the structure of an Arima model object is pretty complex.

Comment: @naught101 Maybe. On the other hand, I managed to answer the question and I know basically nothing about Arima models and had never even installed the forecast package before.

Comment: Perhaps, but Arima should be arima, fitted(fit) returns NULL, and fit$x doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1244215 I don't know what you're talking about. This code runs just as I describe it. (I just re-checked.)

Comment: @user1244215 you need to load the forecast library.

Comment: @joran can you add forecast line to this plot?

Answer (score 18):

The differences you are finding are because the `arima()` function is different from the `Arima()` function.  The former is contained in the basis `stats` package, the lattercomes from the package `forecast` and includes the `fitted()` function to predict over the observed values.