# How do I plot multiple lines on the same graph?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, data-visualization

I am using the R. I am trying to use the "lines' command in ggplot2 to show the predicted values vs. the actual values for a statistical model (arima, time series). Yet, when I ran the code, I can only see a line of one color.

I simulated some data in R and then tried to make plots that show actual vs predicted:

```
#set seed
set.seed(123)

#load libraries
library(xts)
library(stats)


#create data

date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)


#aggregate
y.mon<-aggregate(property_damages_in_dollars~format(as.Date(date_decision_made),
                                                    format="%W-%y"),data=final_data, FUN=sum)

y.mon$week = y.mon$`format(as.Date(date_decision_made), format = "%W-%y")`

ts = ts(y.mon$property_damages_in_dollars, start = c(2014,1), frequency = 12)

#statistical model
fit = arima(ts, order = c(4, 1, 1))
```

Here were my attempts at plotting the graphs:

```
#first attempt at plotting (no second line?)
 plot(fit$residuals, col="red")
 lines(fitted(fit),col="blue")

#second attempt at plotting (no second line?)

par(mfrow = c(2,1),
    oma = c(0,0,0,0), 
    mar = c(2,4,1,1))
plot(ts,  main="as-is") # plot original sim
lines(fitted(fit), col = "red") # plot fitted values
legend("topleft", legend = c("original","fitted"), col = c("black","red"),lty = 1)

#third attempt (plot actual, predicted and 5 future values - here, the actual and future values show up, but not the predicted)

pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 5)
ts.plot(ts, pred$pred, lty = c(1,3), col=c(5,2))
```

However, none of these seem to be working correctly. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? (note: the computer I am using for my work does not have an internet connection or a usb port - it only has R with some preloaded packages. I do not have access to the `forecast` package.)

Thanks

---

Sources:

- [In R plot arima fitted model with the original series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783201/in-r-plot-arima-fitted-model-with-the-original-series/6783814#6783814)
- [R fitted ARIMA off by one timestep? pkg:Forecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197137/r-fitted-arima-off-by-one-timestep-pkgforecast)
- [Plotting predicted values in ARIMA time series in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229948/plotting-predicted-values-in-arima-time-series-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing a couple of things:

1. `fitted` usually does not work on an object of class `arima`. Usually, you can load the `forecast` package first and then use `fitted`.
   But since you do not have acces to the `forecast` package you cannot use `fitted(fit)`: it always returns `NULL`. [I had problems with fitted
   before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378596/namespaces-and-generic-functions-in-r).
2. You want to compare the actual series (x) to the fitted series (y), yet in your first attempt you work with the residuals (e = x - y)
3. You say you are using ggplot2 but actually you are not

So here is a small example on how to plot the actual series and the fitted series without ggplot.

```
set.seed(1)

x <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
y <- stats::arima(x, order = c(1, 0, 0))

plot(x, col = "red", type = "l")
lines(x - y$residuals, col = "blue")
```

I Hope this answer helps you get back on tracks.

[image]