# Plot VAR fitted values with original data R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, time-series, difference

Suppose you have a matrix of time series, where each column is a time series.

Now, suppose you take second differences of this matrix,  (so the data is stationary), using this code:

```
var_train_data <- diff(var_train, differences = 2)
```

and then you estimate this model:

```
var_1 <- VAR(y=var_train_data, lag=9, type="const")
```

Recall that this function `VAR`comes from `vars` package.

How can you plot the original data and the `fitted(var_1)` data? Is there a function to return the fitted data from the VAR to "level"?

I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783201/in-r-plot-arima-fitted-model-with-the-original-series) but with a VAR.

Thanks in advance!!

---

Here is the data:

```
> dput(var_train)
structure(c(8.59225428063812, 8.61632381521795, 8.48941975098913, 
8.42616336163893, 8.4656261753598, 8.49981580266834, 8.50658473928686, 
8.54846279771184, 8.58669260125764, 8.56316032696837, 8.52323490346238, 
8.48186742854092, 8.48127581622944, 8.49729119076164, 8.49055049683316, 
8.58344453055748, 8.66539149708416, 7.9357662604667, 6.05291235942189, 
6.03890804924141, 5.98225560802266, 5.97240914057282, 5.94306180787981, 
6.20137810965131, 6.12654161955374, 5.94624694111468, 5.85594359899009, 
5.80529348520438, 5.8381279297813, 5.94886540621632, 5.89095336551159, 
5.78449385503938, 5.80588769759335, 5.70948049577085, 5.67528501375454, 
5.52325929980363, 5.31085745753021, 5.33500450854624, 5.3938341365814, 
5.45958551414416, 5.62663959880732, 5.67152161243798, 5.87292229474808, 
6.13320939934395, 6.0539450308861, 5.91620206260743, 5.98431404307914, 
5.97698522584315, 6.09421451539306, 6.16657264938364, 6.27079937807193, 
6.32011405804798, 6.31492735684061, 6.33107810311843, 6.44029387009958, 
6.5049295418109, 6.68300329197134, 7.30512711870751, 7.48990882366175, 
7.51140038002074, 7.36108949229449, 7.40527167395002, 7.52991897172882, 
7.48794703789686, 7.28420343801981, 7.03762657251759, 6.94570770568258, 
6.8027650651245, 6.70994292841968, 6.5635196517431, 6.58704241900519, 
6.57918807870411, 6.56763428848419, 6.67249919251384, 6.55714884087979, 
6.44556863637826, 6.64144323226655, 6.69044694236696, 6.64031146877134, 
6.57024614132845, 6.55644009549116, 6.41999492814714, 6.30406385390409, 
6.25618617067998, 6.20859002609663, 6.29478035236011, 6.33882450179958, 
6.27861522839648, 6.36442286111981, 6.40470239932559, 6.38864543562845, 
6.57792182635296, 6.77748387294482, 6.80771392480191, 6.78808230061387, 
6.83179944673993, 6.74635337244069, 6.71228769051817, 6.71323231410622, 
6.87445699358062, 6.99334898488415, 7.02875008260248, 6.99559171234453, 
6.94609768011091, 6.82185333419185, 6.78972221207055, 7.08994524817146, 
6.94355669144552, 6.96382050291509, 7.01613754035382, 7.0956860745406, 
7.10902496856521, 7.0683268590798, 7.09328003338984, 7.03698767140573, 
6.97311732456672, 6.96941465936886, 6.83249279448159, 6.71302370211151, 
6.68918458951307, 6.83687286833789, 6.87816384462923, 6.779867793454, 
6.6690749885188, 6.68210859744981, 6.63725803128446, 6.47906806746391, 
6.63432043737224, 6.57746390143601, 6.63242090143254, 6.51253166492618, 
6.61381121689155, 6.59605370068614, 6.52834257739573, 6.38542432810392, 
6.40417606373692, 6.39057618124397, 6.38557758480921, 6.40206794670863, 
6.38004182339231, 6.33048455580799, 6.31905391015162, 6.18631691346691, 
6.16989597138095, 6.18599200958145, 6.15475193126883, 6.10944958256305, 
6.07359299021025, 6.30235729839158, 6.21488078851159, 6.19123711209895, 
6.13415226194445, 6.10489951928334, 6.10835829857948, 6.17117854049486, 
6.20272828827286, 6.14697144970638, 6.11798126273311, 6.09592248164895, 
6.04625173074978, 5.99916211737789, 6.01626801829834, 6.07798622087923, 
6.06003704039333, 5.96216446139643, 5.8926960131323, 5.91466063648335, 
5.87549237085556, 5.89885310338971, 5.9930422492496, 6.02137002988689, 
6.01266675475859, 6.15176510875538, 6.27125844671076, 6.34813949104671, 
6.50500387674558, 6.50357881390098, 6.4894121494231, 6.48577961874698, 
6.65109576407555, 6.55243995455944, 6.52108609966874, 6.61791214295492, 
6.73192688164199, 6.82964630649759, 6.7830420348085, 6.67163010253559, 
7.35778808496937, 7.68222895818785, 7.65345178297661, 7.75628546245401, 
7.62338589734873, 18.0052565534027, 18.0283161481762, 18.0354203734597, 
18.071119409619, 18.1057986145642, 18.1434464627582, 18.1679613320011, 
18.1724822603554, 18.1626507380013, 18.1735086813587, 18.2048932826437, 
18.2692972785199, 18.2533671856288, 18.2415818049433, 18.2496122176447, 
18.2718727763864, 18.3010161442641, 18.3291390076371, 18.3572538287519, 
18.3507204046193, 18.3600370069532, 18.3939643481435, 18.4165259145903, 
18.4908471052973, 18.4867143437776, 18.4804562806922, 18.469238614477, 
18.4879629103507, 18.5207111296724, 18.5392075918007, 18.549601058126, 
18.5389132074898, 18.5541926126363, 18.5648519425587, 18.6134248798087, 
18.6623309458927, 18.6585086859232, 18.6627389755133, 18.6664151651325, 
18.7001141293336, 18.7124583930686, 18.7555889295117, 18.7668588119494, 
18.7436675451662, 18.7459556596228, 18.7514145615817, 18.7664618044321, 
18.8918838160788, 18.8524507901715, 18.8267408416858, 18.8351746759483, 
18.8659203733722, 18.8520280137673, 18.8947341990718, 18.8888147953761, 
18.8994685106982, 18.9232996525635, 18.8866047503417, 18.9024896904205, 
19.0233652386019, 18.987660272875, 18.9544232700339, 18.9334369249929, 
18.9449183299094, 18.9631673064947, 18.9933965789268, 18.9872237290741, 
18.9873356136058, 19.0123636641398, 19.0206652835947, 19.0270219591515, 
19.1598215152463, 19.1409817254047, 19.1376727583276, 19.1107669946426, 
19.1241264422661, 19.1370331827589, 19.1912655465102, 19.2115823692113, 
19.2158835209359, 19.2414814594526, 19.2701126456528, 19.2843375695361, 
19.457274554838, 19.3897327048706, 19.3892248817594, 19.4122218249334, 
19.4394604950819, 19.4541631046363, 19.4997359433774, 19.5176831040473, 
19.5230181490842, 19.5320146650821, 19.5251016863462, 19.5528663129766, 
19.7183358456188, 19.6474484090812, 19.6534432674726, 19.6576920553381, 
19.6789279209334, 19.7218625314866, 19.7970056245357, 19.8212720524189, 
19.8242227530495, 19.8192388840771, 19.8436023860703, 19.881222941016, 
20.0436302759402, 19.9570453168158, 19.9591040082, 19.9740784817898, 
19.9751993031549, 19.986022300742, 20.0531114406967, 20.0696985627145, 
20.0800828758451, 20.1153963422351, 20.1076549894179, 20.1267044622338, 
20.2723835551353, 20.2393724865888, 20.1653637627644, 20.175313365826, 
20.1653179028692, 20.2067113730004, 20.2925659543297, 20.2949687148603, 
20.3127893925416, 20.3352981379241, 20.3625848609943, 20.4154309157981, 
20.5264488163096, 20.4391570088463, 20.4361213999428, 20.4679188013375, 
20.4735221776474, 20.5104401429986, 20.5802596472874, 20.5970515415252, 
20.6075988336636, 20.6257156522032, 20.6528395142733, 20.7198461324164, 
20.7747860368889, 20.739620648921, 20.7095747158136, 20.6824219109357, 
20.6683460262695, 20.6916705410586, 20.759196128171, 20.7576642433693, 
20.7734082911213, 20.7797650725761, 20.8116082106002, 20.8694893686511, 
21.0404672977562, 20.985356981043, 20.9557258620312, 20.9617164802732, 
20.9759120662088, 20.9794392421448, 21.0620148226635, 21.0624457124599, 
21.0769973151371, 21.0901703250319, 21.098690344787, 21.1226698925968, 
21.2711836808076, 21.2200341433781, 21.207193477524, 21.2331394396842, 
21.2179204523064, 21.2683699326247, 21.3524515602354, 21.2680244710733, 
21.361479141605, 21.3261431820478, 21.26986226303, 21.2991364766223, 
21.4762517489448, 21.3298374568077, 21.3331519252179, 21.3667485789704, 
21.3885075875912, 21.3906997195313, 21.4381231831175, 21.458826223458, 
21.5063778806171, 21.5151033730744, 21.507010374386, 21.5687143378936, 
21.7306835559895, 4.44765724836912, 4.47100191330161, 4.54882158610783, 
4.5440708847657, 4.51747797566305, 4.55880902228773, 4.58341393701683, 
4.64251003043301, 4.67923099142439, 4.67449572095413, 4.61706049834258, 
4.66515462150976, 4.68125825810232, 4.66447683681913, 4.67120538921521, 
4.75098823360583, 4.7865929014467, 4.76411723853929, 4.80166768795887, 
4.80738451939104, 4.72395597727812, 4.70774920353605, 4.73128098441694, 
4.7497092825493, 4.70907556418776, 4.76025128174992, 4.78333093429487, 
4.83897472963042, 4.84221516595959, 4.84570544645976, 4.86534283142894, 
4.83189781246032, 4.88116983304783, 4.93726397688361, 4.9949887298286, 
4.99476493720366, 5.03985402500338, 5.08369093771621, 5.14388523087357, 
5.18085114132468, 5.24643999990121, 5.29616550395191, 5.31221160299188, 
5.19904892834139, 5.11149173059605, 4.91002237688405, 4.74559139066756, 
4.62999621355914, 4.65748259587475, 4.62140362369755, 4.62160891785885, 
4.64311994758678, 4.72234866533005, 4.80015528005185, 4.76255281172576, 
4.81741428916888, 4.78833902844309, 4.84857045098378, 4.88628200385209, 
4.90595450753678, 4.94790389478918, 4.92401525818964, 4.95677349014216, 
5.01088694769778, 4.9503589208899, 4.92948635242132, 4.93119567690321, 
4.95837860539992, 4.97675522372483, 5.02843176452887, 5.06149708771953, 
5.11680002731314, 5.15318428207365, 5.18999785496126, 5.22291283107711, 
5.27233625060222, 5.23506513572608, 5.22540885753388, 5.23894254044616, 
5.2156683767814, 5.20459712839743, 5.16868853558729, 5.18200968431041, 
5.1634206717668, 5.17963852108505, 5.21018392350377, 5.23236124392477, 
5.21618459500301, 5.15529912255812, 5.08809220037847, 5.1198724394553, 
5.14734561157324, 5.15737088983502, 5.14805750597054, 5.13433360782898, 
5.13895940081431, 5.16304129678691, 5.17149369912226, 5.1450893326955, 
5.12587216446798, 5.11899200918883, 5.10413318074705, 5.1160008826641, 
5.13174199954551, 5.1280052744334, 5.11204768607761, 5.10168238434182, 
5.12328408372326, 5.11612649122192, 5.14161587137474, 5.13479881416009, 
5.14165443688476, 5.12847989418342, 5.13034008951874, 5.11006252539728, 
5.07602981399522, 5.04380082747131, 4.9865270245507, 4.93875062722085, 
4.83814457466529, 4.73816812891552, 4.76719339629964, 4.73243951213948, 
4.7435649612657, 4.77654431271813, 4.75791190194754, 4.69814760133106, 
4.63006025665572, 4.62852090719856, 4.62807952037229, 4.56670114439206, 
4.50814804330275, 4.44643563505667, 4.47016149299473, 4.53912223957418, 
4.57221861050859, 4.61097392628225, 4.63675759989718, 4.63305952571057, 
4.63769373351235, 4.63818304039896, 4.66879922486243, 4.65819557081487, 
4.71530442638786, 4.75283411765132, 4.75677199897661, 4.70834590013243, 
4.70931748325188, 4.68986307689509, 4.66007542691547, 4.68658557879665, 
4.71287923105122, 4.74116955758817, 4.75433533727191, 4.79454505679725, 
4.80874809318759, 4.86630450704699, 4.84278723259879, 4.83917234051045, 
4.85488742314064, 4.89072885950008, 4.88255695031045, 4.86964539401132, 
4.85185198871889, 4.88602282140254, 4.89354723701055, 4.80281371512246, 
4.75326969467741, 4.7628424628326, 4.77922033722999, 4.78674176423299, 
4.81556668261512, 4.79146335227998, 4.74952108237436, 4.77041301487697, 
4.71934595594234, 4.74327045521818, 4.7274675891773, 4.76201943815388, 
4.78742822435935, 4.7838694829636, 4.70898722458582, 4.54042300123519, 
4.43046567457835, 4.51451988598857, 4.60392217055997, 4.635511244447, 
4.69067644375465, 4.68405634850711, 4.70605958678574, 4.74618067900467, 
4.83260092214898, 4.58877721775886, 4.5853033584615, 4.58186865729406, 
4.55644763424071, 4.57312995884514, 4.59141300784382, 4.61405195391224, 
4.62539633475001, 4.62855764989542, 4.63775153880854, 4.6400153979937, 
4.63484394226681, 4.66244207350167, 4.66434146018009, 4.67076691372282, 
4.68407880009055, 4.68958339529632, 4.68622457601331, 4.69208811620889, 
4.6940756895394, 4.69428420237835, 4.70035131806994, 4.71249186301022, 
4.7271653599702, 4.7349479901132, 4.74160205558268, 4.74031934574645, 
4.75062724305051, 4.74555258590119, 4.7562138340694, 4.77117641542375, 
4.77731860313779, 4.78678284676528, 4.79153067887926, 4.79406738928742, 
4.81477266396795, 4.80529042610458, 4.82344884188224, 4.84012452381554, 
4.82978062729767, 4.84653955140898, 4.85661455200409, 4.84934319669535, 
4.85983345926684, 4.86432477646786, 4.87752996938969, 4.88896248079701, 
4.89778714881147, 4.90781018324614, 4.89428104718603, 4.88909193570591, 
4.91223232224708, 4.90441909943736, 4.89184080947695, 4.90838616906774, 
4.9120349738912, 4.91193835958192, 4.88849965474606, 4.86952089013496, 
4.82754082787148, 4.82297945991404, 4.83636363788566, 4.81537478739995, 
4.80170678155239, 4.79837796712813, 4.80808503798778, 4.82809683942688, 
4.84168009931907, 4.85375583235012, 4.86250775605786, 4.86576774877652, 
4.85101858001533, 4.88095185322792, 4.889979963576, 4.89811535971474, 
4.91927159620284, 4.93489213808326, 4.94589827772837, 4.93753721242439, 
4.94070114394025, 4.93820671550976, 4.94272951036566, 4.9566005031372, 
4.95762163540098, 4.98371534679409, 4.97127518438922, 4.97300329929901, 
4.97577277168663, 4.99013444353118, 4.98890830668264, 4.99059253380479, 
4.98920233887426, 5.00013814038861, 4.99339203377456, 4.99332756375832, 
4.99585549034717, 4.99514277314306, 4.97378016705823, 4.98107090641032, 
4.95128483491647, 4.94360774445335, 4.94820569518161, 4.97397566869503, 
4.97837258336568, 4.98575124596766, 4.99233525890304, 4.9912972420199, 
5.00502716857625, 4.98574031284931, 4.99974886393147, 5.00248006801806, 
5.00029210629614, 5.00032426635492, 5.00234130906807, 4.99807143017482, 
5.01211153206913, 5.01282969959663, 5.00369558714223, 4.99803646081775, 
4.99122145915995, 4.98203245011163, 4.98898183118227, 4.97676031402907, 
4.97661306140277, 4.97790228452433, 4.97467881736556, 4.97074319702324, 
4.96777121735822, 4.96666260100269, 4.97008836269719, 4.97439822264025, 
4.97499263100689, 4.97356254116369, 4.99650332598755, 4.99359641505544, 
5.00958842621975, 5.00937803525786, 5.01453325868578, 5.01528247340244, 
5.01105287591122, 5.00468878177894, 5.00658901722306, 5.0002693118926, 
4.98932483790769, 4.99855492515587, 4.98814720173172, 4.98315862786098, 
4.97816073933055, 4.97250227511499, 4.97217034019837, 4.9727134145512, 
4.98093640727607, 4.97743699009155, 4.97708205787666, 4.98170032114438, 
4.98999371770747, 4.99342868670462, 4.98710032461129, 4.99711328978229, 
4.99575482652789, 5.00170349753027, 5.01247168017715, 5.01239395194275, 
5.01245423405598, 5.01879001126698, 5.02033652362449, 5.02739033730593, 
5.02651459803757, 5.02453819926525, 5.02388052084628, 5.01926462079431, 
4.98975208317983, 4.97258722645873, 4.9635436865624, 4.96424225452655, 
4.98770778945255, 4.9635436865624, 4.96633503519968, 4.95371214669663, 
4.95441761409803, 4.96214508493582, 4.96772779308498, 4.95159275346247, 
4.95934199970871, 4.97397130972466, 4.96772779308498, 4.97880057057624, 
4.97535347995162, 4.94946885885877, 4.96494033483413, 4.94662996412034, 
4.94378298710842, 7.48320429381319, 7.6561645369399, 7.82110610880829, 
7.59320189720296, 7.68683478110016, 7.95667983810111, 7.59617632139741, 
7.62474227649511, 7.81676325321851, 7.71940521069487, 7.67181853053348, 
8.33880996371242, 7.21094058581954, 8.03822762707727, 7.82261070201569, 
7.82357158274152, 7.83735667738348, 8.1046367156374, 7.80815635609445, 
7.76703032589162, 7.89220083728877, 7.83855143477394, 7.5073939335162, 
8.37816256879826, 7.5059752001373, 8.15552853001404, 7.99048020502086, 
7.87268970278342, 7.90447413791873, 8.36780891138641, 8.01981945164711, 
7.98025535548044, 8.17482965571992, 8.03312420507814, 8.1396225979523, 
8.53154436348939, 8.30064119442864, 8.31217764468587, 8.46515718841819, 
8.29227902146296, 8.37957956757638, 8.77038284745496, 8.38757448056262, 
8.42970131889157, 8.55673020197898, 7.94125019923153, 7.6879198778969, 
9.45050056056844, 8.49521672781314, 8.5173342801255, 8.79041321175791, 
8.62481679196763, 8.6089805031612, 9.02875849754497, 8.71206191409011, 
8.70162108392494, 8.71428574579492, 8.73089101876822, 8.78844251470506, 
9.20696012451967, 6.5096550774221, 9.31509857797606, 9.13789797374865, 
8.81392733764639, 8.85674985041305, 9.24914586810566, 7.91025892946504, 
9.3832351526754, 9.0349150142277, 9.07250596538971, 8.99441603776387, 
9.53980564522775, 8.88032246234735, 9.0418287190433, 9.32660204283357, 
9.10057585013137, 9.08539025332009, 9.49154546126259, 9.14507434057652, 
9.15862717595491, 9.34371391025786, 9.23770140195837, 9.331902300461, 
9.84529784537339, 9.22652292064231, 9.36711817060034, 9.45464102264676, 
9.43080717829243, 9.48542815127549, 9.80315392429245, 9.46220102483428, 
9.49195605787191, 9.58345398545618, 9.63034810064769, 9.62459170291441, 
9.97734143922148, 7.7599692507259, 10.24019393111, 9.83720243907435, 
9.76324132919314, 9.80448476069629, 10.1429407688952, 9.78954063027604, 
9.81148978580127, 9.90999022870695, 9.88337955430856, 9.86638017850479, 
10.3500614614058, 8.04569598345531, 10.5137723520267, 10.0317143144973, 
10.0016019420988, 10.0649053768744, 10.4518094727319, 10.0925802568863, 
10.1154740580661, 10.2417047261218, 10.2102565428829, 9.95096958506337, 
10.736142313028, 10.2104846692811, 10.0464027137144, 10.4566501947458, 
10.213399969191, 10.4108390826055, 10.7497332163144, 10.3922428157884, 
10.3629994803926, 10.5490843518049, 10.5299430900147, 10.5342652815607, 
10.903442654213, 10.523826123055, 9.94829558655345, 11.0676534061714, 
10.7289541973848, 10.7146558087789, 11.1095150342409, 10.7975434766392, 
10.8030323275495, 10.9150557366667, 10.8468764795822, 10.1911966896029, 
11.575751749895, 10.8395599835383, 10.9068704738973, 11.155501263489, 
11.0291969763111, 11.0962769537602, 11.4469279398172, 11.0612218040278, 
11.1062426423224, 11.2517538845846, 11.2333784859651, 10.9841022587667, 
11.7991470802475, 11.2598050882812, 11.254649905487, 11.4720292631746, 
11.3598860229692, 11.4170427738813, 11.766391720184, 11.4134853828265, 
11.4410605118049, 11.5576389232754, 11.5626475736127, 11.5282047555652, 
11.9147793383982, 11.4669389639854, 11.5920019692809, 11.7656439584139, 
11.5489709584581, 11.6145933534541, 12.0526884789762, 11.5721225093198, 
11.5785294086931, 11.9478679038354, 11.7577088515946, 11.644026901156, 
12.282699606583, 11.6893399093708, 11.7081194573217, 12.0745898194066, 
11.8513909555241, 12.0120697218447, 12.3777829279197, 11.9427908749701, 
11.9852440709239, 12.2849763358503, 12.1610242572971, 12.2863478497246, 
12.6987948609176, 8.87626014701704, 8.75781187913873, 8.79677757108755, 
8.86048921162718, 9.42285091166665, 9.15587149508903, 9.07157541184028, 
9.04422296009634, 8.98415367463587, 8.99264229713128, 8.99995926865439, 
8.98630888588454, 9.08279027699937, 9.01801415653217, 9.03092644682495, 
9.13585333120665, 9.3964555249613, 9.31056129804753, 9.21149824677136, 
9.23582853002755, 9.19896921092407, 9.1993094115266, 9.22157244245253, 
9.33255711303986, 9.32050974348142, 9.25734511507957, 9.25346237744606, 
9.21161756310925, 9.57206242922829, 9.53477519401849, 9.44848135105606, 
9.4736925056348, 9.45353618677624, 9.50006144281617, 9.53134203318552, 
9.55522920290037, 9.58433205464551, 9.49975115996635, 9.54279990568933, 
9.4939629665153, 9.8456088597159, 9.80015328006924, 9.76821638323259, 
9.79109456264224, 9.72522763542793, 9.77851709053319, 9.8204171003855, 
9.88434452165958, 9.98640258678757, 9.88349657543331, 9.78072105929449, 
9.91545274615568, 10.0965440644382, 10.069889220858, 10.1071834236742, 
10.0960053864793, 10.0816170924409, 10.0972659507375, 9.98273573064832, 
10.0707648293296, 10.0903422031634, 10.0334967498009, 9.988071454218, 
10.0452755646408, 10.214325988114, 10.1943936821307, 10.20408926276, 
10.1374653682538, 10.1747246925649, 10.1817608649851, 10.1694093867828, 
10.2457147073325, 10.2759167729448, 10.2174707468632, 10.2579653028569, 
10.3132625062745, 10.5801172770154, 10.5266233798438, 10.5287486381328, 
10.4503144592933, 10.481479184849, 10.4934241207427, 10.502542901769, 
10.5494285881606, 10.6156346275554, 10.5119074689424, 10.5311093136153, 
10.5900727521127, 10.832499150024, 10.7930060469324, 10.775718578877, 
10.7531531154054, 10.773311204382, 10.7696395290979, 10.7637570976447, 
10.7977938807946, 10.8750990746633, 10.763894326936, 10.7864939948099, 
10.8084313558315, 11.0190608163543, 10.9799244653747, 11.0238093735289, 
11.0096646409103, 10.9573562063908, 11.0042746906925, 11.0131160377438, 
11.0384446615171, 11.0925921149442, 11.016788345678, 11.0067286524726, 
11.1218140056974, 11.2613143806394, 11.2211796761646, 11.2935015874788, 
11.2367103049134, 11.1817094995799, 11.2157604633905, 11.2061686914688, 
11.2392748154291, 11.4109721102435, 11.3043371225574, 11.2735248395737, 
11.4375261360429, 11.5623874976603, 11.5247175044255, 11.5814242903823, 
11.5093986724378, 11.5000330452891, 11.5579600619228, 11.5311240131655, 
11.5954153362326, 11.6738399129326, 11.57644340322, 11.5655204319799, 
11.6321174901907, 11.8360148309349, 11.8553639635506, 11.8913520673329, 
11.7944527780615, 11.770991474902, 11.8087026529826, 11.7713523360005, 
11.884723151518, 11.9993814545919, 11.8115717892501, 11.8332855179777, 
11.9237740730483, 12.0455787827743, 12.0702342014546, 12.1012197983564, 
12.0183149296719, 12.0336059065465, 12.0269239230024, 12.1132590047525, 
12.5264959691571, 12.2615706812812, 12.0565371292502, 12.2657313524817, 
12.1439258858968, 12.2359003050756, 12.3309092088311, 12.3771893569204, 
12.3071632432092, 12.3196939443778, 12.3000789109455, 12.321469532421, 
12.3683550017493, 12.4759510736235, 12.3701719620075, 12.3835321964786, 
12.372549767611, 12.5961565138223, 12.6077080727407, 12.5909743980745, 
12.5893548765137, 12.5974984744602, 12.6523879936874, 12.6119355657399, 
12.6758307918205, 12.8047085707425, 12.7095434517684, 12.7003715885686, 
12.7865053255695, 13.0041421782442, 13.0268258741114, 13.0190226032443, 
13.0357037893755, 12.9527882182394, 13.0084592868531, 13.0707965999479, 
13.1069788399601, 1.04885832686158, 1.06016074629379, 1.0517956106758, 
1.02907998600003, 1.05054370620123, 1.07261670636915, 1.0706491823234, 
1.0851355199628, 1.08488055975672, 1.08085233559646, 1.081489249884, 
1.08587205516048, 1.07249155362154, 1.05497731364761, 1.05675866316574, 
1.06428371643968, 1.06065865122313, 1.05621234529568, 1.05339905298902, 
1.05787030302435, 1.0658034000068, 1.08707776713932, 1.08626056161822, 
1.10238697375394, 1.11390088086972, 1.12120513732074, 1.11937921359653, 
1.10341241626668, 1.1156190247407, 1.12376155972358, 1.12411603174635, 
1.12183475077377, 1.12994175229071, 1.12956170931204, 1.12199732095331, 
1.11645064755987, 1.12481242467782, 1.13066151473637, 1.13028712061827, 
1.12694056065497, 1.12382226475179, 1.12352013167586, 1.13391069257413, 
1.14763982976838, 1.14481816405703, 1.14852949174863, 1.14182560351963, 
1.14086563926171, 1.14491904045717, 1.14897189333479, 1.14616964486707, 
1.15074750127031, 1.14681353487065, 1.11151754535415, 1.10497749493861, 
1.10963378437214, 1.12415745716768, 1.17507535290893, 1.20285968503846, 
1.22784769136553, 1.23940795216891, 1.254741010879, 1.29442450660416, 
1.30428779451896, 1.31314618462517, 1.32544236970695, 1.33728107423435, 
1.34408499591568, 1.34199331033196, 1.34027541040719, 1.33616830504407, 
1.33360421057602, 1.33332422301893, 1.34717794252774, 1.3502492092262, 
1.35168291803248, 1.35827816606688, 1.36772644852242, 1.36755741578293, 
1.36926148542701, 1.37264481021763, 1.37322962601678, 1.37643913938007, 
1.37906284181634, 1.37644362054554, 1.38911039237937, 1.39412557349575, 
1.40094895608589, 1.40630864159528, 1.40823485306921, 1.4138446752069, 
1.42340582796496, 1.43641264727375, 1.43605231080207, 1.44839810240334, 
1.45451041581127, 1.46166006472498, 1.46774816064695, 1.46930608347752, 
1.47885183796249, 1.49059366171423, 1.49849145403671, 1.51209667142067, 
1.5250141727637, 1.5392257264567, 1.55144303632514, 1.56488453313021, 
1.58308777691125, 1.59737589266492, 1.60896279958586, 1.62553339664661, 
1.63594174408691, 1.65233080464302, 1.67114336171075, 1.6897476078746, 
1.71673790971729, 1.74453973794979, 1.76317526009814, 1.79187692264759, 
1.84186982937622, 1.9460629324144, 2.05986108970089, 2.06767436493269, 
2.0783176148561, 2.08271855277262, 2.09358626977224, 2.09674958523685, 
2.11582742548029, 2.12810020369675, 2.13596929171732, 2.13972610568317, 
2.14456803530813, 2.15013985201827, 2.16007349878874, 2.17165498940627, 
2.18057666565755, 2.19162746118342, 2.20308765886345, 2.21304799942168, 
2.22367586966847, 2.23629862083737, 2.24751866055731, 2.26100586740225, 
2.40972893063106, 2.60366275683037, 2.68572993101095, 2.70501080420283, 
2.6676315643757, 2.6479269687206, 2.64641010174172, 2.69966594490103, 
2.69665303568271, 2.71396750774502, 2.71900427132191, 2.72876269360869, 
2.76276620421252, 2.76620189252239, 2.74632816231219, 2.74196673817286, 
2.72905831066292, 2.75190757584346, 2.77801573354251, 2.84089580821293, 
2.85681823660541, 2.84754572013613, 2.85858396073969, 2.86184353545653, 
2.86958309986952, 2.94279115543111, 2.98631808884879, 3.00648449252989, 
3.00620698598987, 3.15207693676406, 3.27614511764022, 3.32011714920345, 
3.39367422894347, 3.64822360464499, 3.61835354049394, 3.59374251055335, 
3.63237359915986, 3.62209957896007, 3.64554153297999, 3.71611226971083, 
3.76031231050606, 3.80307769833913, 3.77959145461296, 3.74772344909971, 
3.95072671083008, 4.03652777624058, 4.06630193640976, 4.08838169421096, 
4.09074775372752), .Dim = c(192L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("EMBI+", "M2 (pesos)", "Commodity Price index", "emae", 
    "gasto programas SS", "recursos tributarios", "ex_rate")), .Tsp = c(2004, 
2019.91666666667, 12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `fable::VAR`? Then you use a function from a non-standard package it helps to be explicit which package that function comes from.

Comment: No, I meant to use `vars::VAR`. Sorry I will correct it.

Comment: How are you imagining you will be able to focus on all the predicted and original points if there are 7 sets of each and their range is a fairly narrow band around 0 due to the differencing? I can plot it but it's a mess if you display everything at once. Also what is "level"?

Comment: @IRTFM, I am not forecasting any points yet.  I just want the original series that you can plot using `plot(var_train)` and then add `lines(fitted(var_1), col="blue")` So I need the fitted values from the VAR in the same scale as `var_train`.

Comment: I think the fitted results are on the same scale as the `var_train_data` (but not for var_train). In the plots I created it appeared so anyway. They both ranges from a min-max around -4 to 4 with most of the datapoints in the range -1 to 1. It sounds like you are trying to plot incommensurate sets of data. Can you show any theoretic reason why these should be comparable after some sort of undescribed scaling process that forces them to be in the same plotting range?